# Parse Error before Event definition in solidity

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract DieselPrice is usingOraclize {
    function DieselPrice(){

        event one(string description);
        event newDieselPrice(string price);
    }
    function DieselPrice() {
        update(); // first check at contract creation
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
        newDieselPrice(result);
        DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // let's save it as $ cents
        // do something with the USD Diesel price
    }

    function update() payable {
        one("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
        oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The events should not be defined in the constructor of the contract, but in the contract's body itself; see the updated code below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";

contract DieselPrice is usingOraclize {
    event one(string description);
    event newDieselPrice(string price);


    function DieselPrice() {
        update(); // first check at contract creation
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
        require(msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()); // Note: better approach 
        newDieselPrice(result);
        //DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // let's save it as $ cents
        // do something with the USD Diesel price
    }

    function update() payable {
        one("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
        oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
    }

}
```

Note: I have also made a couple of other changes to your code one to make it compile and the other stylistic.

1: I have commented out the following line for a couple of reasons

```
DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // let's save it as $ cents
```

a: the *parseInt* function doesn't seem to exist in the Oraclize code - and isn't defined in your code, so it causes a compilation error. 
b: you haven't defined a type for the variable DieselPriceUSD (also, this should probably have start with a lowercase d).

2: I have updated the check that you perform in the *__callback* function to use require instead of *if _ throw* because this is stylistically a better approach:

```
require(msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()); // Note: better approach
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.And one more is ,when i executed this,it is throwing VM exception:Invalid Opcode.

Answer (score 0):

Event declarations should go outside of any functions.

```
contract DieselPrice is usingOraclize { 

  event one(string description);
  event newDieselPrice(string price);

  function DieselPrice() {
      update(); // first check at contract creation
  }

  function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
    if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
    newDieselPrice(result);
    DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); // let's save it as $ cents
    // do something with the USD Diesel price
  }

  function update() payable {
    one("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
    oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.And one more is ,when i executed this,it is throwing VM exception:Invalid Opcode.